Developer-specific properties in spring boot
How can I define some user-specfic property overrides in spring boot? I'm working with several developers and we'd like to each check in to git a file like "bob_smith.properties" and "bill_jones.properties"; the goal is to have these property files override others. These are not profiles - we are all working on the dev profile. But for instance, one developer might want to set some default properties to disable a complex subsystem, without shutting it down for everyone, and still check in that property setting to git (in their user properties file).
Ideally we'd have one shared piece of code in the application that loads "${username}.properties" which would resolve to different property files in our different environments.

We've tried usign @PropertySource annotations, but these are useless here because they are always overridden by the profile properties (and we are all the same profile - it doesn't make sense to have a separate profile for each developer!).
We've also looked into the EnvironmentPostProcessor route suggested by some, but many others suggested that this is a bad approach too heavily reliant on spring internals.
We'd like to avoid having to manually add the property file to every run profile we create - this seems a very clumsy solution.

Is there a simple way to do this? Or is there some obvious alternative approach I'm missing. I've written this functionality into countless apps before because it provides an elegant way for all the developers to store whatever custom property overrides they are currently utilizing in the repo. Otherwise, we all have to keep the main profile properties checked out all the time and miss each other's property updates  that are meant for the shared code.

Why not just use profiles?  This is precisely their purpose.  On a side note, I would never commit developer-specific anything into the source repository :)

"I would never commit developer-specific anything into the source repository"
Which is fine for you, but its useful to keep everything in a repo, in case my local machine should need to be replaced I have one less bit of setup. Also, having these developer-specific property files in the repo allows other developers to see interesting properties they might not have thought about using during development.
Also our (shared) profile is dev. Having profiles specific to a user, rather than an operating environment, goes against their intended purpose.

Nah, that's the exact purpose of the profiles.  You're mistaken in thinking that environment only represents dev, test, prod, etc.  It doesn't, the environment is defined by the conditions that make it up.  It's perfectly acceptable to have, Bob's environment, Tom's environment, Joe's environment, etc.  Spring uses profiles to differentiate these configurations

I've never heard of a project where, when disucssing environments, they would compose a list like "prod, uat, dev, and also bill and fred and john." If you can cite documentation where profiles are used to support this scenario (dozens of profiles for dozens of developers), I'd welcome it.

From Spring's documentation, "Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments".  Your environment is defined by the configuration that makes it up, not by some arbitrary word you give it.  But you do you, at the end of the day you are the one supporting it.  Consider reading Spring's documentation section titled, "Externalized Configuration"

I think we've articulated the arguments pro and con for that approach sufficiently for anyone who comes across this thread in future, so I'll leave it to them to judge.
